# TableState.getMultiSortMeta() on Primefaces 8

Tags: sorting, primefaces

I'm upgrading from Primefaces version 7 to version 8. There is no longer a `getMultiSortMeta()` method in the `TableState` model available under PrimeFaces 8. Does anyone know how can I replace the following method and get it working in PrimeFaces 8?

```java
public void onSort(SortEvent event) {
    List<SortMeta> sortMeta = ((DataTable) 
        event.getComponent()).getMultiSortMeta();

    channelsViewConfig.setMultiSortMeta(sortMeta);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Primefaces 8 sortMeta is no longer a `List`, but uses `Map<columnKey,sortMeta>` to fetch the sorted collection. This collection is obtained via the attribute `sortMeta` rather than using `sortBy`;

```xml
<p:dataTable id="resultedtable"
             value="#{bean.member}" var="member"
             styleClass="resultedTable" paginator="true"
             paginatorPosition="bottom"
             pageLinks="5"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10"
             sortMode="multiple"
             sortMeta="bean.preSortOrder">

<p:column id="column1" headerText="column1" sortBy="#{member.column1}">
    <h:outputText value="#{member.column1}" />
</p:column>
<p:column id="column2" headerText="column2" sortBy="#{member.column2}">
    <h:outputText value="#{member.column2}" />
</p:column>
```

The backing bean getter for the collection would look something like this:

```java
public Map<String, SortMeta> getPreSortOrder() {      
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    DataTable datatable = (DataTable) 
    viewRoot.findComponent("resultedtable"); 
      
    UIColumn sortColumn = datatable.getColumns().get(0); // Sortby - firstcolumn
    String sortField = sortColumn.getClientId(); // SortField - firstcolumn
      
    SortMeta sortMeta = new SortMeta(sortColumn.getColumnKey(),
        sortField, SortOrder.ASCENDING, null
    );

    preSortOrder = new LinkedHashMap<String, SortMeta>();
    preSortOrder.put(sortColumn.getColumnKey(), sortMeta);
    return preSortOrder;
}
```